# How to fill the value of HTML input from link element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input and I suggest autocomplete list of words from my database using Ajax.
I use bootstrap 4 to design the list, but use `<a></a>` tag instead of the `<li></li>` tag, because bootstrap 4 provides hover effect when using `<a>` instead of `<li>` element for my list.

Everything is working the list of words is displaying, but I don't know how to fill the value of the input when, the user clicks on the desired word.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="index.html" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="team1">First Team</label>
          <input id="team1" type="text" name="team1">
          <div id="autoFil" class="list-group col-sm-12"></div>
            //Here I generate the list using Ajax which looks like this

            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">Keyword 1</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">Keyword 2</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action ">Keyword n</a>
         </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a clickHandler to your anchors, see [this](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for more information.

The clickHandler would then basically use the innerHTML of the clicked a-element and fill any other element's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="index.html" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="team1">First Team</label>
          <input id="team1" type="text" name="team1">
          <div id="autoFil" class="list-group col-sm-12"></div>
            //Here I generate the list using Ajax which looks like this

            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " onclick="fillInput('Keyword 1')">Keyword 1</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " onclick="fillInput('Keyword 2')">Keyword 2</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " onclick="fillInput('Keyword n')">Keyword n</a>
         </div>
</form>
<script>
    function fillInput(val){
       document.getElementById('team1').value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issue in setting the value of input field then you should check [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

It is used like:

```
$('#team1').val('whatever value you want to set');
```

If you are having issue in attaching a click handler for dynamically generated links, then you should be checking this existing question: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)